# File indexing issue in python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, traversal

for this function, i need to traverse through a file and count each line based on certain signifiers. If that certain signifier is present in the line, i need to add the string as a key to the dictionary and increment its value by one each time its present. I am not outright looking for the answer, I am just lost as to what I have done wrong and where I can proceed from here.

Both of the counter variables and the dictionary are returning empty. I need them to return the values based on what is present on a given file.

file line example:

RT @taylorswift13: Feeling like the luckiest person alive to get to take these brilliant artists out on tour w/ me: @paramore, @beabad00bee & @OwennMusic. I can’t WAIT to see you. It’s been a long time coming

code:

```
def top_retweeted(tweets_file_name, num_top_retweeted):
    total_tweets = 0
    total_retweets = 0
    retweets_users = {}
    
    f_read = open(tweets_file_name, "r")
    f_write = open(tweets_file_name, "w")
    
    lines = f_read.readlines()
    
    for line in lines:
        total_tweets =+1
        elements = line.split(":")
        for element in elements:
            if "RT" in element:
                total_retweets =+1
                user_name = element.split()    
                retweet_users[user_name]=+1
    
    print("There were " + str(total_tweets) + " tweets in the file, " + str(total_retweets) + " of which were retweets")

    return retweets_user
```

Comment: Don't post code as images.  Images can't be cut-n-pasted, and are just generally hard for us to work with.  Please edit the question and post the code as plain text.

Comment: Are you sure this is your real code?  You define a dictionary `retweets_users = {}`, but at the end you return `retweets_user` (without an "s" on the end).  Those variable names are not the same.  As posted, this code ought to throw an error.

Comment: Also, `total_retweets =+1` assigns the value "+1", or "positive one", every time.  I think you meant `total_retweets += 1` instead.

Comment: @JohnGordon this is my real code, i added the return statement before posting without checking. I switched to +=1 so im not adding a positive one each time and I'm still getting zeros.

Comment: The behavior of this code depends on the input file, which you have not shown us.

Comment: @JohnGordon I apologize. I just edited the question with an example of a line in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f_read = open(tweets_file_name, "r")
f_write = open(tweets_file_name, "w")
```

You're opening the file for reading and then also opening it for writing, which destroys the existing contents.

Comment: @user20650980 You can show your appreciation by clicking the green checkmark to accept this answer.